# Capistrano occasionally fails to pull git repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, capistrano

Capistrano sometimes fails to pull the newest source from github, but shows no errors.

On several occasions now, `cap deploy` did not pull the latest code from my git repo, but showed no errors in the process.

Repeatingly running `cap deploy` does not fix the issue, but running `git pull origin master` on the actual server does pull in the newest code without any problems.

If I understand correctly, `cap deploy` is by default using the deploy branch - could this be the reason that pulling the master fixes the issue?

// using rails 3

Comment: I'm running into this issue right now and am baffled; thanks for the suggestion on manually running the pull. Hate to admit I hadn't thought of that myself;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to set the 'master' branch as the default branch to deploy from:

```
# Deploy from master branch by default
set :branch, "master"
```

Comment: I no longer rely on Capistrano but would be interested to hear if this solution worked for anyone having this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete a few releases out of /var/www/myapp/releases.